# Accelerate and decelerate to finger position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I have a 3D object on Unity and what I want is simply move this object as soon as the user presses the screen. The problem is that it needs to accelerate first and then, when it is reaching the pressed position, it starts decelerating until it totally stops on that point.

I need this to work in a way that if the user moves his finger, the object will recalculate if it needs to accelerate/decelerate based on his current condition.

I tried [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/680203/spaceship-movement-with-acceleration-and-decelerat.html) example but, it only works for acceleration and it also seems a little confusing. So, I was thinking if someone else have a better and simple idea to solve this. Can physics help with this? If so, how?

My code is in C#.

Comment: I would do as he did, and lerp to the midpoint (or maybe first quartile) and then move a constant speed and then use lerp to go from the constant speed to the endpoint.

Comment: But how do you know when to start the deceleration lerp? The finger can be changing his position at anytime.

Comment: calculate the distance with on touchphase down and touchphase moved and when the distance in touchphase moved is less than 1/2 of the distance do the deceleration lerp

Comment: @CristianoSantos Store the origin, then continuously calculate the distance between the finger and origin, then when the object gets past the 1st quartile maintain a constant speed, and when it passes the third quartile begin to calculate the deceleration

Comment: So, based on my total distance and the current distance of the object to the finger, I can know how much to decelerate right? Could one of you just add a simple algorithm about the deceleration lerp part just to know that I'm not missing something? I will try this tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using unity rigidbody system and simple calculate. This is using mouse position, you can change it to touch.

```
public class MyDragMove : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speedDelta = 1.0f;
    public float decelerate = 1.0f;
    private bool startDrag;
    private Vector3 prePos;

    void Update () {
        this.rigidbody.drag = decelerate; //Rigidbody system can set drag also. You can use it and remove this line.

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Mouse0)) {
            prePos = Input.mousePosition;
            startDrag = true;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            startDrag = false;

        if(startDrag)
            ForceCalculate();
    }

    void ForceCalculate()
    {
        Vector3 curPos = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector3 dir = curPos - prePos;
        float dist = dir.magnitude;
        float v = dist / Time.deltaTime;

        this.rigidbody.AddForce (dir.normalized * v * Time.deltaTime * speedDelta);
        prePos = curPos;
    }
}
```

or just use SmoothDamp toward last position.

```
public class MyDragMove : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speedDelta = 1.0f;
    public float maxSpeed = 5.0f;
    public Vector3 v;
    private Vector3 prePos;

    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            prePos = Input.mousePosition;

        TowardTarget ();
    }

    void TowardTarget()
    {
        Vector3 targetPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3(prePos.x, prePos.y, 10f)); //Assume your camera's z is -10 and cube's z is 0
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp (transform.position, targetPos, ref v, speedDelta, maxSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a little question: If I use `SmoothDamp`, how can I make that when the user releases his finger, it just decelerate in it's last direction?

Comment: SmoothDamp return ref v, when user release you can use the last velocity direction. If object is rigidbody you can set rigidbody.velocity.